# how execute update query in various form field(s)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Just like phpmyadmin update operations. I dont know how much column values I'll update.How can I run different update query for various form field(s). is it possible to perform 1 query.

Suppose I've person table which has three column person_id,name,age.

My html form look like,

```
<form>
 <input type='text' name='name'><br/>
 <input type='text' name='age'><br/>
<input type='text' value='save'>
</form>
```

If I want to update value of'name' field, the query is

```
UPDATE PERSON set name=? WHERE person_id=?
```

If I want to both update values of 'name' and age fields, the query is

```
UPDATE PERSON set name=?,age=? WHERE person_id=?
```

I want whole things in one query

Comment: use some framework like zend or cake

Comment: I use codeigniter @Arun Killu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the current values are outputted in the form you can just update them all in the query. Doesn't matter if they've changed or not.

Answer (score 0):

create a string to update

```
if($_POST['name'])
    $updatestring="name='".$_POST['name']."'";
 if($_POST['age'])
    $updatestring="age='".$_POST['age']."'";
 if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['age'])
   $updatestring="age='".$_POST['age']."',age='".$_POST['age']."'";
 //build query
  $query="UPDATE PERSON set $updatestring WHERE person_id=$_POST[id]"
```